# Django fails to import any package : AttributeError: __name__

Tags: python, django

For some reasons, I had to reinstall Python on my desktop. Since then, my django applications are not working. I can create one, but as soon as I import a package anywhere in the application, I can't run `python manage.py runserver`

I can run another python script, I can start Jupyter Notebooks (and import the exact same packages in them). I also tried to create new projects with the "new" python installed, as soon as I add `import pandas` (or any other packages except django), I have the error.

The error message is quite long :

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 585, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 570, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 288, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 294, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 334, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 350, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djan
go\utils\autoreload.py", line 116, in iter_modules_and_files
    if module.__name__ == '__main__':
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_
apipkg.py", line 171, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(getmod(), name)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_
error.py", line 44, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __name__
```

Comment: Please show us the full error message, no matter how long it is.

Comment: Ok thanks, I edited first post

Comment: In my opinion the issue is because the Environment variable is not setup to recognize pip as a valid command. you need to install pandas in same environment

Comment: Something about your environment is broken, since the autoreloader touching `py._apipkg` breaks things like this. I would recommend a vanilla Python installation instead of Anaconda...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this annoying error after aborting an IDE-refactoring.

I suggest the following to reproduce the problem:

- Revert git changes.
- Make sure there are no cyclic imports in your code.
- Reinstall virtual environment.

Unfortunately the error was still there in my case. So I knew the problem must be with python. And indeed:

- Reinstalling python 3.7 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `pip install django`?

I think when you reinstalled Python you didn't installed packaged like Django

Comment: Yes, Django is installed, I can create apps, I can make migrations and even run server as long as I don't import packages...

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the current Django package and install Django 2.1.5

Use this command on windows:

```
pip install --user django==2.1.5
```