# Django - can't start server

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error when I try to start the server locally (./manage.py runserver).
Posting the question after spending 5 hours of searching solution.

Attached the error stack. I am using Django 2.2.2.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 26, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 585, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 570, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 288, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 294, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 334, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 350, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "/home/santhosh/Desktop/working_dir/piccolo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 116, in iter_modules_and_files
    if module.__name__ == '__main__':
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/py/_apipkg.py", line 171, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(getmod(), name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/py/_error.py", line 43, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __name__
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same question was asked 3 months ago, but didn't receive a definitive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749107/django-fails-to-import-any-package-attributeerror-name

Comment: can you post your manage.py and your pip freeze please was it a fresh project?